# Trouble in Excel.Workbook.SaveAs

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

When I save an excel workbook :

```
xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\output\\excelfile.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, 
  misValue, misValue, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
  misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

it have no proplem.

But

```
String str = "C:\\output\\excelfile.xls";// or get file path from saveFileDialog
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(str, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV,
  misValue, misValue, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
  misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

I found "comexception was unhandled cannot access *.xls",
why is that?

[image]

Comment: It's the same code. Recheck again. Comexception can be random.

Comment: yes, it is the same code, but i don't now why in the secounds code i found exception.

Comment: Have you double-checked?

Comment: i spended one day for this trouble.

Comment: I assure you that if there is the same strings as in your examples - the code will work exactly the same. However, if you are applying in the second example the wrong string - there may be an error.

Comment: i can't post image whith my new account,
plese check this link to give my error : www.freeimagehosting    .net/964dl

Comment: According to this picture, the problem is not with the code, but with the output file. Perhaps, it is already open in this or any other program.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it works for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xlApp = ((TaskPaneView)this.Parent).currentInstance;

    Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks[1];
    var misValue = Type.Missing;
    xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\temp\\excelfile.xls", XlFileFormat.xlCSV,
misValue, misValue, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

    xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\temp\\excelfile.xls", XlFileFormat.xlCSV,
misValue, misValue, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

}
```

On the second SaveAs I get this prompt:

[image]

Comment: i can't post image whith my new account,
plese check this link to give my error : www.freeimagehosting    .net/964dl